# What is the Chinese term for "StackOverflow"？

Tags: translation

What is the Chinese term for "Stack Overflow" website and how do I pronounce it?

Comment: If you mean the Stack Overflow website, we usually don't translate the name and just call it Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you are not asking for the Chinese name of he website then please edit your question to ask instead "What is the Chinese term for a stack overflow?" - This is a case where punctuation, capitalization, and the choice of words such as "name" vs "term" (or "word" or "called" etc) makes all the difference in the world.

Comment: Apologies if it seems nitpicky or anal but it's still ambiguous whether your asking about overflowing a computer stack or the main Stack Exchange website. Proper nouns in English are capitalized and computer terminology is not. Also none of your tags give much hint to which you want `\-:`

Comment: @hippietrail I am asking with regards to the <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a> website

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The answer is "Stack Overflow" doesn't have a Chinese name. But if somebody were to translate the name of the website literally, they would base it on the original meaning in computers, in which case I'm sure either or both Albus Shin's and pataklama's answers would be correct.

Comment: If you want to talk to a Chinese about the website you'd better to say "stackoverflow.com" without translation. If you use the Chinese such as "堆栈溢出", I think that nobody can figure out the website.

Comment: We don't translate this, because this is a special caller name, we only know that's a collection of question-answering forum.

Comment: I think this is a interesting question though closed. Many foreign companies are likely to have a native name when entering Chinese market. For example, HP for `惠普`, MircoSoft for `微软`, Google for `谷歌` and recently, LinkedIn for `领英`. I think if someday StackOverflow can enter Chinese market, it'd also consider to have a native name. Actually I have one suggestion - `思达客栈`. `思` means thoughts, `达` means arrival, `客栈` the name for some kind of traditional form of hotel+restaurants in China.

Comment: Mainland China version in SC: 栈溢出/堆栈溢出, in TC: 棧溢出/堆栈溢出, Hong Kong & Taiwan version in SC: 堆叠溢位, in TC: 堆疊溢位. The word "stack" is translated as "堆栈(SC)/堆棧(TC)" in mainland China, but "堆叠(SC)/堆疊(TC)" in HK & TW. (SC = Simplified Chinese, TC = Traditional Chinese)

Answer (score 2):

```
Stack Overflow == 堆栈溢出

堆栈 == stack

溢出 == overflow
```

This is a very technical term. Only people who work in programming and other related fields would be able to understand this.

Comment: Like the other answers, this one is about the technical term in computing but the OP was specifically asking about the Chinese name for the website StackOverflow, and there is no Chinese name for it. Anyway it's closed as off topic because of that now.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified Chinese: 栈溢出, or 堆栈溢出

Traditional Chinese:棧溢出, or 堆棧溢出 means Stack Overflow in English.

栈 or 堆栈 means stack, and 溢出 means overflow.

Pronunciation:

```
栈溢出 zhàn yì chū

堆栈溢出 duī zhàn yì chū
```

Comment: Whoever voted down this answer, please give out the reason.

Comment: I voted this down because the OP was asking about the name of [the website Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). (At least that's how it clearly seemed to a native English speaker by using "named" and capitalizing each word.) I also commented on the other answer and on the question for clarification in case this was not intended.

Comment: Alright, fair enough.

Comment: It's not an answer to the question.

Comment: Simplified Chinese: 栈溢出。
Traditional Chinese:堆疊溢位。
Mainland and Taiwan use different translations in jargon terms.

Answer (score 1):

```
Simplified Chinese characters: 栈溢出  (used in mainland China)
Traditional Chinese characters: 堆疊溢位 (used in Hong Kong and Taiwan)
```

Mainland and Hong Kong/Taiwan use differnt translations in jargon terms. `Stack` is a jargon term meaning `the memory which obeys the rule of FILO (first in last out) or LIFO (last in first out)` in computer programming, which is translated to `栈` in mainland China, but is translated to `堆疊` in Hong Kong and Taiwan. `Overflow` is a jargon term meaning `number too large and not able to express in the computer` in computer programming, which is translated to `溢出` in mainland China, but is translated to `溢位` in Hong Kong and Taiwan.

Comment: Sadly the OP was actually asking about the Chinese name of the website [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), run by the same people that run this very site. He wasn't asking about the technical term `\-:`

Comment: @hippietrail  The "StackOverflow" can **only** be a technical term in Chinese. There is no such thing as a common term for "StackOverflow" in Chinese.

Comment: Exactly. That's what a correct answer should say because that's what the OP is asking about. I asked them to clarify and that's what they said.

Answer (score -1):

According to wikipedia: 堆疊溢位
(http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A0%86%E7%96%8A%E6%BA%A2%E4%BD%8D)

Comment: How do you pronounce it ??

Comment: This answer links to a page specifically on the subject of a computer's call stack overflowing. The OP specifically asked for the Chinese name of a website that doesn't have a name in any other language. If the OP actually meant to ask "what's the Chinese term for a stack overflow?" then it should be edited as such.